# Como criar um modal corretamente para fazer alteração de dados usando w3

Tags: php, javascript, w3.css

Gostaria de saber como implementar um modal para receber os dados de alteração.
Eu estou usando o **w3**.
Na Imagem Abaixo quando o usuário apertar o botão AUSENTE tem que abrir um MODAL
com as informações do paciente da linha. Nome, tel, o plano de saúde dele, nr do cartão do plano etc.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Teoricamente tenho que fazer uma requisição php para popular o modal, mas o problema é que não sei onde colocar essa requisição ou se a forma que estou chamando o modal para esse caso é errado

Abaixo Mostro como chamo UM OUTRO MODAL quando aperto o botão ENCAIXE
HTML

```
    <td> <input type="button" class="add"
         onClick="chama_consulta_01_modal('',
                                          '{$row['id_m_h']}','{$diaN}',
                                          'atendimento')" 
         value="ENCAIXE"></td>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
function chama_consulta_01_modal(id_linha_tabs,id_m_h, dia,veio_de)
{   
  document.getElementById('id_consulta_01_modal').style.display='block';
  document.getElementById('id_veio_de').innerHTML = veio_de;    
  document.getElementById("id_m_h_div").innerHTML = id_m_h;
  document.getElementById("data_div").innerHTML = 
           document.getElementById("id_data_atual").innerHTML;
  document.getElementById("index_tab_div").innerHTML = dia;
};
```

O código acima faz aparecer este MODAL
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O código que uso para produzir os MODAIS é assim:

```
<div class="w3-container">
    <div id="id_consulta_atendimento_02_modal" class="w3-modal" style="padding-top:200px">
        <div class="w3-modal-content">
            <center>   
            <header class="w3-container w3-teal"> 
                <span onclick="document.getElementById('id_consulta_atendimento_02_modal').style.display = 'none'" 
                      class="w3-button w3-display-topright">&times;
                </span>

                <h2>STATUS PACIENTE</h2>                
            </header>
                </center>  
            <div class="w3-container">                

                <div class="row"><br>
                    <div class="col-md-1"></div>
                    <div class="col-md-10" style="text-align: center">
                        <div class="form-group">                            
                            <b><font color="blue" size="3"><label  id="id_ca02m_nome_paciente"><></font><b>                            
                        </div>
                    </div>     
                </div><br>
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>CONVÊNIO...:</legend>
                    <div class="row">

                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <select name="cb_convenio" class="form-control" id="id_cb_convenio" autofocus style="width:90%;" required="true">
                                <option value="0" disabled selected hidden> 
                                    SELECIONE
                                </option>  
                                <?php include 'consulta_atendimento_02_modal_cb_convenio.php'?>                                                                                                    
                            </select>
                        </div>     
                    </div><br>
                </fieldset>                

                <br>
                <div class="row" align="center">
                    <div class="col-md-12">                     
                        <button onclick="document.getElementById('id_consulta_atendimento_02_modal').style.display = 'none'" type="button" class="w3-button w3-red">FECHAR</button>                     
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <footer class="w3-container w3-teal">
                <p>Modal Footer</p>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

O código acima é um protótipo para o MODAL em questão que estou querendo fazer.
Esse código esta em um arquivo .php. Ele esta na pagina da CONSULTAS MARCADAS:

```
<html CONSULTAS MARCADAS>

<body>
  CÓDIGO..CÓDIGO..
CÓDIGO..CÓDIGO..CÓDIGO..
 <?php include 'selecionar_paciente_modal.php' ?>
 <?php include 'status_paciente_modal.php' ?>
 <script>
    CÓDIGO..CÓDIGO..
 </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Quando eu coloco o código php na status_paciente_modal.php para fazer a conexão e montar o MODAL com os dados do paciente, esse código não funciona corretamente pois quando a página CONSULTAS MARCADAS entra, o código do include status_paciente_modal.php é disparado e da erro na página.

Uma forma que encontrei foi colocar atributos no botao:

```
<td>
<input type='button' class='add A' 
      data-paciente_nome="<?php echo ($row['nome']);?>" 
      data-paciente_cpf="<?php echo ($row['cpf']);?>" 
      data-id_convenio="<?php echo($row['id_convenio_fk']); ?>"
      id_consulta_ca_01_busca ="<?php echo($row['tem_consulta']);?>"                                                 
      onclick= status_paciente(self)
      value='AUSENTE'>
</td>
```

Ai na função status do paciente pego esses atributos:

```
 function status_paciente(botao)
{                 
document.getElementById('id_consulta_atendimento_02_modal').style.display='block';
document.getElementById("id_ca02m_paciente_nome").innerHTML = 
                        botao.getAttribute('data-paciente_nome');
document.getElementById("id_ca02m_paciente_cpf").innerHTML = 
                        botao.getAttribute('data-paciente_cpf');
document.getElementById("id_cb_convenio_02_modal").value = 
                        botao.getAttribute('data-id_convenio');
}
```

Funcionar o código acima funciona. Ai um amigo meu programador sempre diz..:
**"CÓDIGO BOM É AQUELE QUE FUNCIONA"** 
Sei que quando estamos sendo precionados pelo TEMPO/CHEFE isso é bem verdade. :)
Mas neste instante NÃO é o caso :).
**Então volto a questão original do POST.. *Como/Onde devo implementar o código php
para fazer uma consulta na base é popular o MODAL?*** 
 
Pois como falei anteriormente apesar de saber fazer consultas php e chama-las em vários locais e de vários modos, nesta situação em particular não obtive sucesso. Certamente pela minha falta de experiencia na linguagem :)
Espero ter exposto minha NECESSIDADE claramente.
 
Caso alguém entenda e consiga sintetiza-la seria legal :) e eu agradeceria :).
Caso alguém "PENSE" que entendeu minha necessidade por favor..não altere nada.. me escreva e tentarei explicar de outra forma :)
 
Abraço a todos :)

Comment: Se estiver disposto a usar `JQuery`, recomendo `ajax()`

Comment: Bom dia @I_like_trains . Obrigado pela dica :).  Teria algum exemplo do que esta falando.. ou algo para ler?? Abraços

Comment: Tem aqui a documentação do `ajax`, darei um exemplo em breve

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 1):

Em `ajax()`, você pode executar `php` que vem fora do ficheiro.

Comecemos pelo início.

Se eu bem entendi, cada linha da tabela é referida a um `id` da base de dados, gerada pelo `while`. (Falta esse código apresentado mas supomos que seja assim)

Daremos o nome por exemplo `$dados`, sendo assim a variável que recebe os dados do `while`, no botão onde carrega, acrescente `data-id="<?=$dados['id']; ?>"`, deste modo todas as linhas ficaram identificadas e nunca iguais.

Agora passemos ao `script`

Primeiro deverá verificar se carregou lá, seria assim o código:

```
$(".add").click(function(){       //Visto que o botão tem esta `class`, podemos ir buscar assim
  var id = $(this).data("id");    //O $(this) irá buscar a seguinte informação de onde carregou
$.ajax({
  url: "buscar_modal.php",        //Ficheiro onde iremos buscar as informações
  data: "id="+id,
  type: "POST",
  success: function(e){           //Variável e servirá para escrever no modal ou mostrar erros, se houver
    console.log(e);               
    $("#id_consulta_atendimento_02_modal").html(e);
  }
})
});
```

O script está feito, agora passemos para o `buscar_modal.php`

O início do ficheiro deve começar com a verificação da variável enviada, se foi recebida ou não

`if(isset($_POST['id'])){`

Com isto verificará se foi enviada. De seguida iremos selecionar da base de dados a linha desejada.

Irei supor que está a usar `mysqli`.

```
require "ligacao.php";
$select=mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM nome_tabela where id = '".$_POST['id']."'") or die ("Erro 01");
$mostra=mysqli_fetch_assoc($select);
```

Com a linha selecionada só resta apresenta-la.

```
<div class="w3-modal-content">
    <center>   
    <header class="w3-container w3-teal"> 
        <span onclick="document.getElementById('id_consulta_atendimento_02_modal').style.display = 'none'" 
              class="w3-button w3-display-topright">&times;
        </span>

        <h2>STATUS PACIENTE</h2>                
    </header>
        </center>  
    <div class="w3-container">                

        <div class="row"><br>
            <div class="col-md-1"></div>
            <div class="col-md-10" style="text-align: center">
                <div class="form-group">                            
                    <b><font color="blue" size="3"><?=$mostra['nome']; ?></font><b>                            
                </div>
            </div>     
        </div><br>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>CONVÊNIO...:</legend>
            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <select name="cb_convenio" class="form-control" id="id_cb_convenio" autofocus style="width:90%;" required="true">
                        <option value="0" disabled selected hidden> 
                            //Executar um while com as informações desejadas
                        </option>  

                    </select>
                </div>     
            </div><br>
        </fieldset>                

        <br>
        <div class="row" align="center">
            <div class="col-md-12">                     
                <button onclick="document.getElementById('id_consulta_atendimento_02_modal').style.display = 'none'" type="button" class="w3-button w3-red">FECHAR</button>                     
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <footer class="w3-container w3-teal">
        <p>Modal Footer</p>
    </footer>
</div>
```

Com isto irá apresentar o que deseja.

Comment: Bom dia @I_like_trains . Muito legal o link que tu passou para eu poder ler. Obrigado.  Muito maneiro o seu exemplo :) Um pergunta: os "PARAMETROS"  do $.ajax({ , , , }) tem que ter uma ordem??? Eu uso essa função mas de um modo diferente e com os parametros em uma ordem diferente. E do modo que uso no paremetro  success: function(e){ } eu retorno um echo da página .php que é um id ou palavra. Não sabia que dava para retorna o  $("#id_consulta_atendimento_02_modal").html(e);  Na Segunda-Feira (08/11/2018) vou fazer uma outra página da forma que você demonstrou :) . Obrigado e Abraços.

Comment: Os parametros podem ter qualquer ordem, mas em termos de organizaçãp, deixe o `success` para ultimo